# Cell borders are not printed (except on 1st page) when table spans multiple pages in Firefox

Tags: php, html, css

When I print the following page, the borders on the second page are not shown (see image below). The HTML tags are working though. How can I get the borders also on the second page?

```css
@media print {
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
}
```

```html
<table  width="100%"  bordercolor="#000000"  style=" border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"  border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Borders are shown on the first page, but not on the second]

Answer (score 1):

try to set the border-collapse to initial and define the attribute cellspacing=0 in the table. It solve the problem to me

Answer (score 0):

```html
table {
       border-collapse: separate;
        border :  0px solid #000000;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 11pt;
    width: 100%;
    border-color:  #000000 ;
    border-right: 1px solid;

}
```

i am using   border-collapse: separate;

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
}
table,tr,th,td {
color:red;
border :  1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>head 1</th>
  <th>head 2</th>
  <th>head 3</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Col 1</td>
  <td>Col 2</td>
  <td>Col 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```