# Html table borders not printed on the second page, Firefox only

Tags: firefox, browser, printing, html-table

The table borders are not printed on the second page, only with Firefox, this problem doesn't occur on Chrome, IE or Opera.
It is important to note that this is happening only lately.

[image]

**Update :**
I tried these answers but still not fixed :[Same behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390661/cell-borders-are-not-printed-except-on-1st-page-when-table-spans-multiple-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
<!--
@media print {
    table.your_particular_class {
        border-collapse: unset;
    }
}
-->
</style>
```

If you don't have a class just use table

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs if the css property border-collapse is set to collapse or separate. Try to set the css border-collapse property to "border-collapse:initial", it resolve to me, and don't forget to set the attribute cellspacing=0 to the table.